# New measure and expectation formula

Tags: probability-theory

If we define new measure to be $Q(A) = \int _AZ(\omega)dP(w)$, then $E_Q(X)=E_P(XZ)$. But why this euqality is true? Is there any formal way of showing it? Does $dQ(w)=Z(\omega)dP(\omega)$ hold? Why? What is the formal justification of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of $Q$ we know that
$$
\mathrm{E}_Q[\mathbf{1}_A]=Q(A)=\int_A Z\,\mathrm dP=\mathrm{E}_P[\mathbf{1}_AZ],
$$
so that we immediately have $\mathrm{E}_Q[X]=\mathrm{E}_P[XZ]$ for all $X$ of the form $X=\mathbf{1}_A$ for some measurable set $A$.

We can now extend this to the more general case where $X$ is any integrable random variable (with respect to $Q$) by first showing that it holds for non-negative simple functions, then for any non-negative function, and, lastly, for any general integrable function. This is a standard argument used all the time in measure theory / probability theory.

Comment: So in general $dQ(w)=Z(\omega)dP(\omega)$ doesnt make sense yeah?

Comment: @luka5z "So in general dQ(w)=Z(ω)dP(ω) doesnt make sense" Sorry but what are you talking about exactly? The identity dQ(ω)=Z(ω)dP(ω) is the way Q was *defined*.

Comment: I mean $P_Q(A)=\int _AdQ(w)=\int _Ad(\int _AZ(\omega)dP(w))=\int _AZ(\omega) dP(w)$. Can we write it like this? What is the formal explanation of it? That d and integral "cancel each other"

Comment: Maybe the other way - what is the meaning of $dP(\omega)$ except for containing information about the measure that we are integrating with respect to. I mean are any operations on that symbol allowed and why? Like above

Comment: Eh, what's $P_Q(A)$?

Comment: Sorry, it meant to be $Q(A)$

Comment: The formal explanation is written in my post.